# python дебаггер ругается, но работает

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, pycharm

Дебаггер, при запуске сразу же выдаёт ошибку следующего характера:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/home/hedgehogues/programs/pycharm-community-2017.2.2/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 1134, in do_it
>
> result = pydevd_vars.evaluate_expression(self.thread_id, self.frame_id, self.expression, self.doExec)
>
> File "/home/hedgehogues/programs/pycharm-community-2017.2.2/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_vars.py", line 356, in evaluate_expression
>
> Exec(expression, updated_globals, frame.f_locals)
>
> File "/home/hedgehogues/programs/pycharm-community-2017.2.2/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_exec.py", line 3, in Exec
>
> exec exp in global_vars, local_vars
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> NameError: name 'sample' is not defined

Во время выполнения (step next) в разные моменты времени аналогичная ошибка может выскакивать произвольно. Гугление ни к чему особенно не приводит. Пробовал переставить pyCharm на новый. Обновил всё. Без результатов.

---

В силу того, что я не смог найти решения, [задал вопрос в баг-трекере](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-25845) pycharm

Comment: Я бы попробовал наоборот откатить PyCharm до более старой версии, и попробовать на нем. Возможно это свежий баг PyCharm, поэтому о нем ничего в интернете нет.

Comment: @insolor хорошо, попробую. Но, раньше я долго не обновлялся, поэтому версия была старая. И я не уверен, что связь прямая

Comment: А операционная система какая?

Comment: @nick_gabpe ubuntu 16 04